# inserting value into PHP multi array

Tags: php

i am new in PHP coding, i wanna add some variable value in a multi  array dynamically,  below is my code...

```
   $books = array (
      "finality"=> array (
       "title"  => 1,
       "author" => 2,
       "thumbnail" => 3,
       "file" => 4,
       "comment" => 5,
      ),
    "science"=> array (
         "title"  => 1,
         "author" => 2,
         "thumbnail" => 3,
         "file" => 4,
         "comment" => 5,
      ),
    "morality"=> array (
        "title"  => 1,
        "author" => 2,
        "thumbnail" => 3,
        "file" => 4,
        "comment" => 5,
      ),
 )
```

i want to add variables like.    $title, $author, $pic2, $pic, $comment,     in one array like     $books['morality'].     please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand your question correctly, this is what you want.

```
$books['morality']['title'] = $title;
$books['morality']['author'] = $author;
$books['morality']['thumbnail'] = $pic2;
$books['morality']['file'] = $pic;
$books['morality']['comment'] = $comment;
```

If that's not what you are looking for try and be more precise in what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like to add a new item to the array.

Does the following look like what you need? If not, can you please try to clarify what it is that you would like?

```
$books[ $category ] = array(
  "title"  => $title,
  "author" => $author,
  "thumbnail" => $thumbnail,
  "file" => $file,
  "comment" => $comment
);
```